# I have git repo connected with a heroku project which I delete. Now how can I upload that same repo to a new heroku project?

Tags: git, github, heroku

I had a git repo which is connected with a project in heroku which I deleted. How I create a new heroku project and want to upload that same repo, I am facing an error saying ,

```
remote: !       No such app as immense-sierra-17813.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/immense-sierra-17813.git/' not found
```

This "immense-sierra" was my previous heroku project which was connect with my git repo.
Now whenever I try to push this repo to a new heroku project I'm facing that error. What should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+change+remote

Comment: `heroku git:remote -a [app name]`